Can LaTeX handle the expandable arguments?
I have DIY an newcommand \displaygrade to show info, the syntax is as below:
\display*[teacher-name<default=admin>][teachar-age]{stu1-name}{stu1-score}{stu2-name}{stu2-score}


[star*]  if starred, it will hide the second optional arguments, and show nothing
Other parameters' meaning is clear in its name

I make the following MWE：
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\displaygrade}{sO{admin}ommmm}{
    \vspace{1em}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=display the grade,fonttitle=\bfseries]
        Teacher: \emph{#2};
        \IfNoValueF{#3}{
            \IfBooleanF{#1}{Teacher's Age = \emph{#3};}
        }\par
        stu1 info: name = \emph{#4}, score = \emph{#5};\par
        stu2 info: name = \emph{#6}, score = \emph{#7};
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace{1em}
}
\begin{document}
\displaygrade[TEACHER]{AAA}{100}{BBB}{99}
\displaygrade[teacher][30]{AAA}{100}{BBB}{99}
\displaygrade*[teacher][23]{AAA}{100}{BBB}{99}
\displaygrade{AAA}{100}{BBB}{99}
\end{document}

which results that:

Now MY QUESTION is:

Can we refine the parameters setting, for any numbers of infomation pairs,such as \displaygrade{AAA}{100}{BBB}{99},or more \displaygrade{AAA}{100}{BBB}{99}{CCC}{100}{DDD}{99}{EEE}{59}, can parse the arugments automatically and use for-loop to display them
I found the code of arguments setting a little smelly, for the infomation pair didn't connected in forms like {(AAA,99),(BBB,100)}, is there any advise for design the newcommand above?


You can do it with a change in syntax. The name-grade pairs are given inside a single argument; spaces and endlines between braced items aren't relevant, so you can also get a better layout of the code. Any number of students is allowed (well, not more than 231, but I don't think it's a problem).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\displaygrade}{sO{admin}om}{%
  \par\addvspace{1em}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title=display the grade,fonttitle=\bfseries]
    Teacher: \emph{#2};
    \IfNoValueF{#3}{%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{Teacher's Age = \emph{#3};}%
    }\par
    \printgrades{#4}
  \end{tcolorbox}\par\addvspace{1em}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printgrades}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {} {#1}
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \int_if_odd:nTF {##1}
     {% odd index, print info and name
      stu\int_eval:n { (##1+1)/2 }~info:~
      name~=~\emph{##2},~
     }
     {% even index, print score
      score~=~\emph{##2}
      \int_compare:nTF { ##1 = \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq }{.}{;}\par
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\displaygrade[TEACHER]{
  {AAA}{100}
  {BBB}{99}
}

\displaygrade[teacher][30]{
  {AAA}{100}
  {BBB}{99}
  {CCC}{100}
  {DDD}{60}
}

\displaygrade*[teacher][23]{
  {AAA}{100}
  {BBB}{99}
}

\displaygrade{{AAA}{100}}

\end{document}



If someone has more than 2³¹ students, then LaTeX is the least of their problems…
